# Is there a way to edit the Last Modified Date of an object stored in Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I am migrating some of my static content to Amazon S3 and I wanted to know if there was a way to edit the Last Modified Date of the object when moving into my S3 bucket?

As you can guess, by default, the Last Modified Date is set to the creation date of the object, so all of my legacy content is having incorrect dates associated to it.

Thanks for any info or pointers.

EDIT: After doing some additional digging, it looks like that can not be edited (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata). So, I guess back to the drawing board for the best way to associate original creation date to my objects in S3. Looks like I will need to add some custom metadata to the object.